# Ubuntu 9.10 and Squid 2.7 Transparent Proxy TCP_DENIED

Tags: proxy, dhcp, squid, ubuntu-9.10

We've spent the last two days trying to get squid 2.7 to work with ubuntu 9.10. The computer running ubuntu has two network interfaces: eth0 and eth1 with dhcp running on eth1. Both interfaces have static ip's, eth0 is connected to the Internet and eth1 is connected to our LAN.

We have followed literally dozens of different tutorials with no success. The tutorial here was the last one we did that actually got us some sort of results: http://www.basicconfig.com/linuxnetwork/setup_ubuntu_squid_proxy_server_beginner_guide.

When we try to access a site like seriouswheels.com from the LAN we get the following message on the client machine:

---

ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

Invalid Request error was encountered while trying to process the request:

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.seriouswheels.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko)   Chrome/5.0.307.11 Safari/532.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept:   application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Cookie: __utmz=88947353.1269218405.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __qca=P0-1052556952-1269218405250; __utma=88947353.1027590811.1269218405.1269218405.1269218405.1; __qseg=Q_D
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Some possible problems are:

Missing or unknown request method.

Missing URL.

Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).

Request is too large.

Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.

Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

---

Below are all the configuration files: /etc/squid/squid.conf, /etc/network/if-up.d/00-firewall, /etc/network/interfaces, /var/log/squid/access.log. Something somewhere is wrong but we cannot figure out where.

Our end goal for all of this is the superimpose content onto every page that a client requests on the LAN. We've been told that squid is the way to do this but at this point in the game we are just trying to get squid setup correctly as our proxy.

Thanks in advance.

### **squid.conf**

acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24
acl SSL_ports port 443      # https
acl SSL_ports port 563      # snews
acl SSL_ports port 873      # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 631     # cups
acl Safe_ports port 873     # rsync
acl Safe_ports port 901     # SWAT
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access deny purge
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
icp_access allow localnet
icp_access deny all
http_port 3128
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid/cache1 1000 16 256
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Package(.gz)*)$    0   20% 2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
acl shoutcast rep_header X-HTTP09-First-Line ^ICY.[0-9]
upgrade_http0.9 deny shoutcast
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache
extension_methods REPORT MERGE MKACTIVITY CHECKOUT
cache_mgr webmaster
cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy
hosts_file /etc/hosts
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

---

**access.log**

---

1269243042.740      0 192.168.1.11 TCP_DENIED/400 2576 GET NONE:// - NONE/- text/html

---

### **00-firewall**

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X

echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128

---

### **networking**

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 142.104.109.179
netmask 255.255.224.0
gateway 142.104.127.254

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must tell squid that it is setup as a transparent system

Instead of

```
http_port 3128
```

You need

```
# enable the transparent option for interception caching
http_port 3128 transparent
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your help. I modified the config file and restarted squid. I'm getting a different error now: ACCESS DENIED. Below is my access.log and the text I see in the client browser. I think we're getting close here.  

LOG  

1269292020.375     20 192.168.1.10 TCP_DENIED/403 1475 GET http://digg.com/ - NONE/- text/html  
1269292020.450      0 192.168.1.10 TCP_DENIED/403 1497 GET http://digg.com/favicon.ico - NONE/- text/html

Comment: CLIENT ERROR
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://digg.com/

Access Denied.

Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.


Generated Mon, 22 Mar 2010 21:07:00 GMT by PoleMesh360 (squid/2.7.STABLE6)

Comment: I found my error. This ip was incorrect: acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/24 => acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24. Now I'm going across the proxy. Thank you very much!